# findAssocs can't get results

Tags: r, tm

I have a corpus variable *df_tdm* by using *tm* package as shown below:

```
> df_tdm
<<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 214552, documents: 1)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 214552/0
Sparsity           : 0%
Maximal term length: 126
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
```

When I use findAssocs function to find correlated words with *like*, it returns *numeric(0)* instead of matrix of relevant words. Why is that happen.

```
> findAssocs(df_tdm, "like", .1)
$like
numeric(0)
```

Comment: Have you tried with a lower threshold in the findAssocs function ? Maybe something like .05 or lower.

Answer (score 0):

The last parameter in the function findAssoc is the minimal correlation requiered to output a term.
The empty output in your exemple might be due to the value of your threshold. Try a lower value and it should work.